# Scroll to div on another page in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a React project and I want to redirect to #categories div on main page...when I click on a link on navbar of the main page (where #categories div is) it works, but when I click on that link on another page (categories div is on another page and it should redirect me to localhost:3000/#categories), the href is good but it only redirects me to that page, not to categories div on the page.

I have tried writing a function to do it and also checked if the div name (id) is correct, checked if link works and everything.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect to a `div` instead use `section` tag

```
<section id="categories">
   <div></div>
</section>
```

Now the same `localhost:3000/#categories` href would work. [Read More](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-redirect-to-a-particular-section-of-a-page-using-html-or-jquery/)

Comment: The final solution was that I had to create a function with a timeout because the div wasn't loaded so it couldn't scroll to it.